# Submitting form with body-parser

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to understand how routing works with express.

With some code redacted, I have the following in my `server.js`

```
const multer = require("multer"); //for uploading image
const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); //for adding employee(below)
app.get("/employees/add", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './views', 'addEmployee.html'));
});

app.get("/images/add", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './views', 'addImage.html'));
});

app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {
    data.getAllEmployees().then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error was encountered: " + err);
    });
});

app.get("/images", (req, res) => {
    let imagePath = './public/images/uploaded';
    fs.readdir(imagePath, function(err, items) {
        if (items.length == 0) {
            console.log("No images");
            res.send("Error reading images directory<br/><h3>Return to <a href='/'><em>HOME</em></a></h3>");
        } else {
            //res.json(items);
            var finalString = "Images: " + JSON.stringify(items) + "<br/><h3>Return to <a href='/'><em>HOME</em></a></h3>";
            res.send(finalString);
        }
    });
});


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/images/uploaded",
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.use(express.static("./public/images/uploaded"));
app.post("/add-image", upload.single("imageFile"), (req, res) => {
    const formFile = req.file;
    res.send("<p>Your submission >> " + JSON.stringify(formFile) + " was successful</p><br/><h3>Return to <a href='/'><em>HOME</em></a></h3>");
});
```

My `data-service.js` has a function defined as,

```
module.exports.addEmployee = function(employeeData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        (typeof employeeData.isManager === 'undefined') ? false : true;
        employeeData.employeeNum = employees.length + 1;
        employees.push(employeeData);
        resolve(employees);
    });
}
```

Where the `employees` array resides in an `employees.json` file.

I have no issues getting the uploading images working. It uploads, and sends me back a response. Now, I am trying to get Adding a New Employee to work with `body-parser`, however I am running into a few issues.

My `server.js` waits for:

```
app.get("/employees/add", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './views', 'addEmployee.html'));
});
```

And then redirects to my `addEmployee.html` which has the action, `action="/add-employee"`, redirecting back to my `server.js` with the route,

```
app.post("/add-employee", (req, res) => {
    //do something
});
```

I have tried calling it with something along the lines of,

```
app.post("/add-employee", (req, res) => {
    data.addEmployee();
    //etc
});
```

having defined `addEmployee` as in the second code snippet.

And this, (obviously, otherwise I wouldnt be here lol), doesn't quite work. I feel like, although syntax may be an issue, I am misconstruing the routing logic here. What am I missing?

Comment: Try and use addEmployee() as middleware by putting it into your route like app.post("/add-employee", addEmployee, (req, res, next) => { on the first line.

Comment: I merged your idea, and got this:

app.post("/add-employee", (req, res) => {
    data.addEmployee(req.body).then((data) => {
        res.redirect("/employees");
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error was encountered: " + err);
    });
});

it's working now (kinda) thank you.

Comment: My issue now is that it adds employeeNum towards the end of the newly created object: https://i.imgur.com/4L9sGnK.png. Thoughts?

Comment: keys in an object are in arbitrary order see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and look for `order`. If the order of the keys are important then you could use an Array or Map